# How do I find the shortest substring of a search term which returns results?

Tags: python

I am working on a task where given the name of an item on a menu, I have to find recipes which are similar to that item. Currently, to achieve the most accurate results, I start from the last word of the name of the item and check if the API returns any results. I keep adding words to the search term, querying the API each time, until no more results are returned.

For example, given the phrase "creamy ranch sauce" I would try "sauce", then "ranch sauce", then "creamy ranch sauce". If there were no results for creamy ranch sauce I would backtrack to ranch sauce.

My problem is that this is too slow as many API calls are required. Is there some way to process the string so that it finds the base name of the food before making the API call? Here is what I have:

```
search_terms = query.split()
end = len(search_terms)
result = is_valid_query(search_terms[-1])
while result:
    end -= 1
    if end == 0:
        break
    query = " ".join(search_terms[end - 1 :])
    result = is_valid_query(query)

def is_valid_query(query):
    with urlopen(get_search_url(query)) as response:
        data = parse_response(response)
        return not data["count"] == 0
```

Comment: Can you ask whoever provides the API to support multiple search terms?

Comment: @IainShelvington unfortunately not, the site which the API is for does not have such a feature